# ¿Como cambiar nombre de tablas y modificar automáticamente los procedimientos almacenados?

Tags: mysql

buenos días primeramente y gracias por tomarse su tiempo a responder.
Bueno mi problema radica que ocupo modificar el nombre de una tabla así como la de sus atributos pero tengo varios procedimientos almacenados que utilizan campos de esa tabla. 
La pregunta es como le hago para que se modifiquen los SP cuando modifique los nombres de la tabla, o por lo menos saber que procedimientos utilizan atributos de dicha tabla.
PD: Estoy trabajando en MySQL

Comment: [este enlace puede ayudarte](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/84bb2fa5-7f78-4c5e-ab37-e8c2e9ec46f5/how-to-update-the-table-name-in-all-the-stored-procedures?forum=transactsql)

Answer (score 0):

No hay manera de hacer refractor directamente... Lo que se me ocurre es que exportes esa tabla y todos los triggers, procedimientos y funciones y ya teniendo el codigo aplicar un rename desde tu editor, identifica cuales procedimientos, funciones y triggers modificaste y eliminalos de la base de datos para volverlos a crear con los que modificaste en el editor, aun si fueran... 100 seria rápido así.

Espero haber sido de ayuda. saludos.